# Emacs keybinding involving forward slash

Tags: emacs, elisp

in emacs, I would like to remap `\C-/` from undo to my own function commenting the current region or the current line (if no region is selected). When I try something like this:

```
(global-set-key "\C-/" 'comment-or-uncomment-region-or-line)
```

I'm getting an error that

```
error: Invalid modifier in string
```

I was trying different ways of the keybinding, unfortunately with no success and googling for `\C-/` was not very helpful either.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What shortcut do you use for Undo, then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-/") 'comment-or-uncomment-region-or-line)
```

Comment: Yeah, I can do so in 5 minutes ;)

Comment: As for why: key-sequences started as strings (i.e. sequences of characters, which back then were also bytes), because that made sense back in the text-terminal days.  But there's no such character as "home", or "mouse-1", so we had to change key-sequences from strings to vectors (i.e. sequences of objects).  Strings are still accepted for backward compatibility reasons, but you can't use them for mouse bindings, or for bindings to keys that do not have a corresponding character (ASCII (and Unicode) includes characters for C-a and C-_ but not for C-/).  Instead of `kbd` you can use `[?\C-/]`.

Comment: This still doesn't work for me. I get a message "C-_ is undefined" in minibuffer, if I press this combination. In the virtual consoles in Linux it's even funnier, C-/ acts as delete... I'm confused.